# Raspberry GPIO event

Tags: python, subprocess, gpio

I'm writting a script to play a song when a button is pressed in my raspberry Pi, however I face a problem to run it.

When I'm running the bellow script in Thonny IDE, it's working well, each time I press the button, the song is played, however when I try to run it from the terminal (`python /home/pi/Documents/Python/Douce_nuit/Douce_nuit.py`) the program stop imediatly and therefore the song can not be played.

It's as issue as I would like to launch this script at the startup of the raspberry (I included in rc.local `sudo python /home/pi/Documents/Python/Douce_nuit/Douce_nuit.py`)

Could you please help me to understand why it's working when launch from the IDE but not from the terminal?

My code is:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import subprocess, sys

def playsong(channel):
    opener = "open" if sys.platform == "darwin" else "xdg-open"
    subprocess.call([opener, '/home/pi/Documents/Python/Douce_nuit/douce_nuit.mp3')

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(10, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

GPIO.add_event_detect(10, GPIO.RISING, callback=playsong))
```

Comment: If you're running this in a REPL in the IDE, the program will stay running as long as the REPL session is open. As a standalone script though, once the end of the file is reached, the program will exit. You'd need to do something to prevent the script from exiting. A call to `input` at the end of the script will prevent it from exiting until the user hits `enter`, but that's a bit of a hacky way. You could have a second loop at the end that will only exit when the user hits another button (it would loop until a boolean flag is set to false for example).

Comment: Thanks, I added an input and it now work when run from the terminal. However, the script is still not launched automatically even though I ask that in the rc.local file. Any int?

Comment: I've never had stuff autorun on my Pi4B, so I can't help with that unfortunately. From a quick search though, GPIO usage requires escalated privileges, which may not be what autorun programs are run with (likely because running everything under root would be a security risk).

Comment: @Baptiste running from `rc.local` should have the correct privileges. You should log the output and errors from your code somewhere to see if it's failing with a useful error message. If you are getting errors and you're not sure what they mean, you may want to open a new question.

Comment: Setup your DT to use `gpio-keys` driver and create a simple handler shell script on the event of that button. No Python code is needed, really.

Comment: larsks and @0andriy, I'm quite new at programming and don't now much Linux interface, could you guys provide me with a bit more details on both your solutions, please?  Thanks a lot

Comment: http://www.armadeus.org/wiki/index.php?title=GPIO_keys, https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=115394 for the starter. So, first try to get an event from your GPIO button by properly formed DTS (either as platform modified or as an overlay) with `gpio-keys` driver (or `gpio-keys-polled` in case the hardware hasn't IRQ capability on the given GPIO line / controller). When you have `evtest` or simple `od -x /dev/input/event<X>`, where `<X>` is a number of your event, working we can continue.

Comment: I finally add the commande to `.bashrc` which solved partially the problem. Last solution looks better but I clearly have trouble to get inot it..